# PHP - Upload a CSV file & print specific rows

Tags: php, csv

I'm working on a web project in which a user should be able to take a .csv generated by an Asana project export and import it so it prints specific rows.

I am actually able to import the file :

```
if ( isset($_POST["submit"]) ) {

   if ( isset($_FILES["file"])) {

        //error while uploading the file
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
            echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
        }

        else {
           //error message if file already exists
            if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
             }

            else {
            //Uploads file in the upload/ folder
            $storagename = "uploaded_file.txt";
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $storagename);
            echo "<strong>Stored in:</strong> " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
            }
         }
      } else {
             echo "No file selected <br />";
     }
}
```

and then dump the data :

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("upload/" . $storagename, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num champs à la ligne $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

So, in order to print some specific rows, I thought of this, which would take the data from the 11, 12, 13 & 14 rows :

```
$kilometrage = $data[11];
$stationnement = $data[12];
$perdiem = $data[13];
$depenses = $data[14];
```

But sadly, I am not able to figure this out.

Is someone have a clue/idea/tip? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What happened when you tried your code? Did you put it in the for loop and echo the 4 variables?

Comment: @Tim Please see answer below !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I did figured out with this, by looping, setting and echoing the variables. I still don't know if it's the best way of doing it but it actually works :

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("upload/" . $storagename, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;
$kilometrage = $data[11];
$stationnement = $data[12];
$perdiem = $data[13];
$depenses = $data[14];
        for ($c=0; $c < 1; $c++) {
            echo "<table style='min-width:1000px;'><tbody><tr>";
            echo "<td style='width:25%'>" . $kilometrage . "</td>";
            echo "<td style='width:25%'>" . $stationnement . "</td>";
            echo "<td style='width:25%'>" . $perdiem . "</td>";
            echo "<td style='width:25%'>" . $depenses . "</td>";
            echo "</tr></tbody></table>";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```